# angular2 table with dynamic rows and columns

Tags: angular, dynamic

How do I create a table with dynamic columns and rows in angular2

I have the data coming from a rest service and captured in this observable

```
this._physicalDataService.getPhysicalData().subscribe(res=> this.data = res)
```

I can display the rows dynamically through this code. How do I make the columns and the column headers dynamic too ie how can i extract all the JSON keys in an array to put another loop on top.

To clarify my backend service may return different datasets with different columns and row and I want to show them dynamically on a page.

```
               <thead class="no-bd">
                        <tr>
                          <th>Id</th>
                          <th>Number</th>
                          <th >Employee Name</th>
                          <th >Manager Name</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>

                        <tr *ngFor="let tablerows of data">
                          <td>
                          {{tablerows.row_id}}
                          </td>
                          <td>{{tablerows.number}}</td>
                          <td >{{tablerows.employee_name}}</td>
                          <td >{{tablerows.manager_name}}
                          </td>
                        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use same *ngFor on your `<th></th>` too.

But For that you will need to calculate length of Object.It Will give you no of elements in each Array.

```
var custObject = new Object();
myArray["firstname"] = "Gareth";
myArray["lastname"] = "Simpson";
myArray["age"] = 21;
this.objLength = Object.keys(myArray).length;  // Calc length of Object i.e. 3
```

After You Have length of Object , You can render your `<th>` block that many times using below pipe:

```
<th *ngFor='#key of 5 | demoNumber;let i=index'>
Column{{i}}
</th>
```

Pipe:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from 'angular2/core';

@Pipe({name: 'demoNumber'})
export class DemoNumber implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let res = [];
     for (let i = 0; i < value; i++) {
        res.push(i);
     }
    return res;
  }
}
```

This will calculate no of Object fields & then ngFor will render Coulmn+index for each field.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You. These hints helped a lot. I got it working

Comment: @SaurabhVerma glad to hear. close the question by accepting the answer if your query is resolved