# How to set table heading dynamically in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am getting JSON data and I am storing JSON data on my property.

```
this.ResultData_search=data.json().extras.ResultData 

this.ResultData=[

  {
        "First_name": "xx",
        "Email": "xxxx",
        "Phone": "xxx",
        "countryCode": "+91",
        "order_datetime": "xxx",
        "status": 11,
        "DeviceType": 3,
        "orderId": "59081a04c9ff6852a49dd32a",
        "orderseqId": "E00002347",
        "orderType": 1,
        "CustomerID": "xx",
        "pickAddress": "xx",
        "dropAddress": "xx",
        "pickLatitude": 17.4369414,
        "dropLatitude": 17.43673,
        "dropLongitude": 78.36710900000003,
        "paymentType": 2,
        "itemDescription": "",
        "receiverName": "uday",
        "receiverPhone": "xx",
        "itemName": "sanjay",
        "deliverycharge": "199",
        "bookingType": 1
      }
      }]
```

I want to set all keys as table heading and data as table rows. I referred to the below links[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40713580/angular2-table-with-dynamic-rows-and-columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810318/dynamically-loading-columns-and-data-in-to-table-in-angular-2)

Link 2:[Dynamically loading columns and data in to table in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810318/dynamically-loading-columns-and-data-in-to-table-in-angular-2)

Any plunker will be very helpful to me.

Comment: i created one pipe but it is printing table heading in tr only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key solution is to convert the Object `ResultData` into an array of keys. Then you can easily iterate over it. You can get the keys of the object using `Object.keys(this.ResultData)`.

*component.ts*

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td *ngFor=" let key of keys">
        {{key}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor=" let res of ResultData">
      <td *ngFor=" let key of keys">
        {{res[key]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  ResultData=[
  {
        "First_name": "xx",
        "Email": "xxxx",
        "Phone": "xxx",
        "countryCode": "+91",
        "order_datetime": "xxx",
        "status": 11,
        "DeviceType": 3,
        "orderId": "59081a04c9ff6852a49dd32a",
        "orderseqId": "E00002347",
        "orderType": 1,
        "CustomerID": "xx",
        "pickAddress": "xx",
        "dropAddress": "xx",
        "pickLatitude": 17.4369414,
        "dropLatitude": 17.43673,
        "dropLongitude": 78.36710900000003,
        "paymentType": 2,
        "itemDescription": "",
        "receiverName": "uday",
        "receiverPhone": "xx",
        "itemName": "sanjay",
        "deliverycharge": "199",
        "bookingType": 1
      } 
      ]
  constructor() {
  }
   keys: string[]=[]; 

  ngOnInit() { 
       this.keys= Object.keys(this.ResultData[0])
  }
   
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This [link](https://webcake.co/object-properties-in-angular-2s-ngfor/) has an alternative way of using a pipe to convert a JSON object into an array.

**Here is a [working plunkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/Us97K0EG2YShnigT8huo?p=preview)**

Regading the following part :

```
    <tr *ngFor=" let res of ResultData">
      <td *ngFor=" let key of keys">
        {{res[key]}}
      </td>
    </tr>
```

`ResultData` is an array of items. For each item we will create a table row, and we will display the content of each item. That is why we repeat `<tr>` for each item `res` in the array `ResultData`.

Then, for each item `res` in the `ResultData` we will iterate over the array of `keys` we prepared earlier in the ts code. For each item `key` in the `keys` we will display the value of item as `{{res[key]}}`.

Comment: i am getting table headings like 0,1,2, ...but i want table heading like First_name,Email,Phone ..like this.Thanks in advance

Comment: Thank sir,u saved me.i already marked as correct answer.but my reputations is below 15

Comment: sir,could you explain  these lines if u don't mind                                                                         <tr *ngFor=" let res of ResultData_search">
      <td *ngFor=" let key of keys">
        {{res[key]}}
      </td>
    </tr>

Comment: @AmrElAdawy.  I am working on similar requirement to dynamically load table headers and data. But the {{res[key]}} does not work. When I use {{res["name"]}} in place of key the actual field name in single or double quote it works..<tr *ngFor=" let res of resultData">
                    <td>{{res["podName"]}}</td>
                    <td *ngFor=" let key of keys">
                      {{res[key]}}
                    </td>
                  </tr>