# Array of Json(dynamic keys) + table format +angular5

Tags: node.js, angular, angular5

I am receiving a JSON as response from my  API, i have to display that data into table structure.

Consider JSON as follows:

```
[
{
"key1":"value1",
"key2" :"value2"
},
{
"key1":"value3",
"key2" :"value4"
}
]
```

But `key1` and `key2` is not fixed, it will change each time, so i have to display the content received from API as Table structure. I referred a lot nothing is regarding dynamic keys.
 I referred this https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/angular-material-part-4-data-table-23874582f23a

But have to display dynamic content.

**EDIT**

I want the below structure:

```
key1    key2
value1  value2
value3  value4
```

[Create Table from JSON Data with angularjs and ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209117/create-table-from-json-data-with-angularjs-and-ng-repeat)  answerBy `SantoshK` is want i need i think so but its showing blank table for me.

Comment: can u please add some of your code?

Comment: So you would like to iterate through your json key/value with index is that right ? 
Like `json[0].key = "key1"` and `json[0].value = "value1"`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/material2-beta11-vmwjpe?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @Sravan In your code suppose `name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;` is not fixed means if you dont know the keys , is my case

Comment: in html there is no any key.. it is dynamic

Comment: @Sravan if keys are dynamic how can we create  an interface??

Comment: If you dont want material, I ll give answer for you

Comment: @Sravan means??

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (It is just reference only):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <title>Web Page Design</title>
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
   </head>
   <table>
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Value</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="tableId">

      </tbody>
   </table>
   <script>
      function sayHello() {
         var sample = [{"key1":"value1","key2" :"value2"},{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}]


         for (key in sample){
             for (currVal in sample[key]){
                $('#tableId').append('<tr><td>'+sample[key][currVal]+'</td></tr>')
             }
         }

      }
      sayHello();
   </script>
   <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: whether i have to use jquery must here??

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, you should take **`Object.keys`** to get the `dynamic` key values of `object`

**Component:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  candidature = "test";
  data =[
{
"key1":"value1",
"key2" :"value2"
},
{
"key1":"value3",
"key2" :"value4"
}
]

getKeys(schedule_data){
  return Object.keys(schedule_data);

}
 }
```

**HTML:**

```
<table>  
<th *ngFor="let sch of getKeys(data[0])">
  {{sch}}
      <div *ngFor="let schedule_data of data">
        {{schedule_data[sch]}}
    </div>
</th>
</table>
```

[**Here is a working DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbkxqs?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: i found a link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864288/how-to-set-table-heading-dynamically-in-angular-2 and its upto what i expected

Comment: please check my demo, it also creates dynamic keys

Comment: @Subburaj, is that fine?

Comment: @Subburaj, I changed my answer to make it in the format you needed. Please check