# Dynamically change column values in angular material mat-grid-list

Tags: angular, typescript, flexbox, grid, angular-material

I am using mat-grid-list :https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/examples

So in the documentation it is given (you can refer the link below) :

Adding tiles that span multiple rows or columns
It is possible to set the rowspan and colspan of each mat-grid-tile individually, using the rowspan and colspan properties. If not set, they both default to 1. The colspan must not exceed the number of cols in the mat-grid-list. There is no such restriction on the rowspan however, more rows will simply be added for it the tile to fill.

But my Issue is that I want a structure like this :

there will be three rows and in the first row 3 columns, 2nd Row 4 columns and 3rd row 2 columns. Like a collage frame. the number of columns per row will be send dynamically.

Is there any solution or an alternative way of achieving this?
refer this Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhsrY.png

Comment: If you want me to create such a grid like from your picture in code, just let me know,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can change the columns and rows dynamic for every tile.

```
<mat-grid-list cols="{{desired_columns}}" rowHeight="{{desired_rowHeight}}">
    <mat-grid-tile
        *ngFor="let tile of tiles"
        [colspan]="tile.cols"
        [rowspan]="tile.rows"
        [style.background]="tile.color">
       {{tile.text}}
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

That's one way by using a list e.g. `tiles` that you have in your `typescript` class and set the values dynamic.

---

Or you can create your `mat-grid-tile`s manual in html, but still set different column and row spans for each `tile`.

```
<mat-grid-tile [colspan]=1 [rowspan]=2>
    content
</mat-grid-tile>
<mat-grid-tile [colspan]=4 [rowspan]=1>
    content
</mat-grid-tile>
<mat-grid-tile [colspan]=3 [rowspan]=2>
    content
</mat-grid-tile>
```

Comment: How can we change the content dynamically? let's say I want to add a sub component to content, is it possible?

Comment: @SherwinAblañaDapito Sure that is the concept of Angular. Just create any sub component and insert it's `selector` as the content of a `mat-grid-tile`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: 
[angular2 table with dynamic rows and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40713580/angular2-table-with-dynamic-rows-and-columns) or by using multiple mat-grid-list by providing different row height ratios and columns for different rows :

```
<mat-grid-list cols="{{your_desired_columns}}" rowHeight="{{your_dynamic_ratio}]">
    <mat-grid-tile>1</mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile>2</mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile>3</mat-grid-tile>
   ..
    <mat-grid-tile>n</mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: Can you please check the question again I have updated an Image. Is that achievable from your answer? Thank you.

Comment: Actually I wanted to change the cols value for every mat-grid-tile, That way I could set [colspan] value and then get the required output. but the Issue is I cannot change the value of each mat-grid-tile. I can only set the "cols" value once

Comment: Then I recommend using table structure with given columns. And dynamically assigning colspan and rowspan values to it. Try creating it statically by using basic html, then converting it into dynamic angular code.