# How To Dynamically Change Col and RowHeight in mat-grid-list

Tags: angular

I found most of the answer of how to dynamically change the number of cols and height in mat-grid-list from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50258632/dynamically-change-column-values-in-angular-material-mat-grid-list)

How do I add the 'rem' or 'px' value?

Here is my component.ts code:

```
 constructor(public mediaObserver: MediaObserver){
  this.watcher = mediaObserver.media$.subscribe((change: MediaChange) => {
    this.activeMediaQuery = change ? `'${change.mqAlias}' = (${change.mediaQuery})` : '';
    switch(change.mqAlias) { 
      case 'xs': { 
         //statements; 
         this.desired_columns = 3;
         this.desired_rowHeight = .33;
         this.tiles = [
          { text: 'Buy and sell good stocks using conservative indicators.', cols: 3, rows: 1, color: 'lightgreen', fontSize: '1', fontFamily: 'Roboto Condensed', paddingTop: '0vh', marginLeft: '0vh', marginRight: '0vh'},
          { text: 'Buying and selling ', cols: 3, rows: 2, color: '', fontSize: '.6' , fontFamily: 'Roboto Condensed', paddingTop: '5vh', marginLeft: '0vh',marginRight: '10vh'  },
          //{ text: 'Try BuySell For Free', cols: 2, rows: 1, color: '', fontSize: '1', fontFamily:  'Roboto Condensed', paddingTop: '0vh', marginLeft: '0vh', marginRight: '0vh'},
          { text: 'Six', hasButton: true, cols:2, rows: 1, color: '', fontSize: '2',fontFamily: 'Rubik', paddingTop: '0vh', marginLeft: '0vh', marginRight: '0vh' },
        ];
         break; 
      } 
      case 'sm': { 
         //statements; 
         this.desired_columns = 5;
         this.desired_rowHeight = .33;
         console.log("Expecting sm, getting ", change.mqAlias);
         this.tiles = [
          { text: '', cols: 5, rows: 1, color: '', fontSize: '1', fontFamily: 'Rubik', paddingTop: '0vh', marginLeft: '0vh', marginRight: '0vh', },
          { text: 'Buy and sell good stocks using conservative indicators.', cols: 2, rows: 1, color: 'lightgreen', fontSize: '1', fontFamily: 'Roboto Condensed', paddingTop: '0vh', marginLeft: '0vh', marginRight: '0vh'},
          { text: '', cols: 1, rows: 3, color: '', fontSize: '1',fontFamily: 'Rubik', paddingTop: '0vh', marginLeft: '0vh', marginRight: '0vh' },
          { text: 'want image', imageUrl: "../../assets/img/bluemoon.PNG" ,hasImage: true, cols: 2, rows: 3, color: '', fontSize: '.5', fontFamily:  'Rubik' , paddingTop: '0vh' , marginLeft: '0vh', marginRight: '0vh'},
          { text: 'You do not have to be a technical entrepreneur to make money. Buying and selling good stocks are money makers.  Buy Sell shows the buy sell dates of the last five years to show what your return on using this tool. We calculate the closing indicators of MACD, 10 day moving average, and slow stochiastic of your stock.', cols: 2, rows: 2, color: '', fontSize: '.6' , fontFamily: 'Roboto Condensed', paddingTop: '5vh', marginLeft: '0vh',marginRight: '10vh'  },
          //{ text: 'Try BuySell For Free', cols: 2, rows: 1, color: '', fontSize: '1', fontFamily:  'Roboto Condensed', paddingTop: '0vh', marginLeft: '0vh', marginRight: '0vh'},
          { text: 'Six', hasButton: true, cols:2, rows: 1, color: '', fontSize: '2',fontFamily: 'Rubik', paddingTop: '0vh', marginLeft: '0vh', marginRight: '0vh' },
        ];
```

This is the component.html code:

```
<mat-grid-list cols="{{desired_columns}}" rowHeight="{{desired_rowHeight}}" [gutterSize]="'0px'" *ngIf="mediaObserver.isActive('lg') || mediaObserver.isActive('xl')">
    <mat-grid-tile
        *ngFor="let tile of tiles; let i = index"
        [colspan]="tile.cols"
        [rowspan]="tile.rows"
        [style.background-image]="tile.color"
```

I tried "this.desired_rowHeight = '.33rem';" I get this error.

"Error: Invalid value ".33rem" set as rowHeight."

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I added the error to the question. This is the error "Error: Invalid value ".33rem" set as rowHeight.'

Comment: Just use it like this `this.desired_rowHeight = '0.33rem';`

Comment: I tried 100px instead of .33 rem and it works. maybe rem is too small. That was it, I changed it to 33 rem and it works.

Comment: I have posted an answer with a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reproduce the error I have used the example of `mat-layout-list` from [official documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview) you can check it on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fxdocx)

The problem here is that `'.33rem'` is not translated to `'0.33rem'` since it's a string value.

There are few ways how to fix this

Just change `.33rem` to `0.33rem`

```
this.desired_rowHeight = '0.33rem';
```

Or you can do it like this

```
this.desired_rowHeight = .33 + 'rem';
```